# How would I evaluate the following trigonometric expression?

Tags: trigonometry

$\csc^{-1}\left({-2\sqrt3 \over 3}\right)$

I've tried using a calculator, but it only shows "math error."  I don't know how to process it by hand.  The answer is $-60°$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\csc^{-1}\left({-2\sqrt3 \over 3}\right)&=-\csc^{-1}\left({2 \over \sqrt3}\right)\\
&=-\sin^{-1}{\sqrt3\over2}\\
&=-{\pi\over3}=-60°
\end{align}$$